# Настройка текста

Tags: html, css

Начал работать над новым дизайном игрушки. И не получается настроить текст. Хотелось бы настроить позицию текста, а то никак не получается. Пишу текст, а он посредине выскакивает, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Выложите исходники на http://jsfiddle.net/ или другое место, где их сразу видно и не надо скачивать.

Comment: @oOKomarOo Исходный код не должен размещаться где-то в недрах файлообменников в архивах. Весь необходимый текст должен быть в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

таблица:

```
<table class="niz">
 <tr>
   <td valign="top">
     <div style="margin: 20px">123</div>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Это как пример, но я не поклонник такого кодинга, но в данной ситуации мне кажется по другому сложно поступить.